# IR2110 PSpice simulation - Convergence Problems

Tags: pspice

I have a simple simulation circuit for the IR2110 in PSPice. From my understanding, the convergence errors are related to each circuit in particular and that the IR2110 is very prone to convergence problems. I am open to suggestions what I can modify.

Here are the things I have tried:

- "increase the 
  ABSTOL = 1pA to 10pA or larger or increase RELTOL = 0.001 to 0.01 or larger." As the document included with the model suggests.
- Increase/Decrease Run to time (default is 100u) to 10u/1000u and Maximum step size to: default, 1n, 10n, 10u.
- Check/Uncheck "Use GMIN stepping".

Orcad Capture version is 9.2, so no autoconverge option.

Below is the schematic, and errors:

```
These voltages failed to converge:

    V(X_U1.MD4_Uvbs_2)        =   -10.00GV  \   -10.00GV
    V(X_U1.MD4_Inv4_1)        =     4.897V  \         0V
    V(X_U1.MD4_Nor2_2)        =   -10.00GV  \   -10.00GV
    V(X_U1.MD4_Inv6_3)        =    10.00GV  \    -9.64GV
    V(X_U1.MD4_Nor2_4)        =  -756.95KV  \     4.897V
    V(X_U1.MD4_Inv6_1)        =    1.546MV  \    4.897uV
    V(X_U1.X_MD4_Uvbs_Comp.5) =     4.897V  \         0V

  These supply currents failed to converge:

    I(X_U1.E_MD4_Uvbs_ABM18)  =    30.72MA  \    86.40MA
    I(X_U1.E_MD4_Uvbs_ABM19)  =   -30.72MA  \   -86.40MA
    I(X_U1.X_MD4_Uvbs_Comp.E1) =   -19.61nA  \         0A
    I(X_U1.V_MD4_Inv4_V)      =    43.87MA  \    94.33MA
    I(X_U1.V_MD4_Nor2_V)      =  -756.96KA  \   -4.897uA
    I(X_U1.V_MD4_Inv6_V)      =    10.00GA  \   -42.53KA
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the load is connected wrong, it should be in relation to GND (pin 2 of L2 connected to ground, not V1).

Second, ABSTOL set to a few uA (10-100) and RELTOL to 0.1. This way it works, even if the output calculation aren't very precise.

Thank you!